# Как зарегестрировать реализацию для нескольких интерфейсов в ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp-net-core-mvc

Я создал сервис, реализующий несколько интерфейсов, и пытаюсь зарегистрировать его на DI в ASP.Net Core. В моём случае, я хочу чтобы сервис был `Singleton`, и при запросе любого из реализуемых интерфейсов, потребитель получал один и тот-же экземпляр.
Проще говоря, я хочу что-то вроде

```
class Impl: IService1, IService2 { }
...
services.AddSingleton<IService1, IService2, Impl>();
...
public SomeController(IService1 service1, IService2 service2)
{
    service1 == service2 // true, потому что это один и тот-же экземпляр
}
```

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете зарегистрировать саму реализацию как сервис (с тем типом, который имеет сама реализация), и использовать этот сервис для получения реализаций отдельных интерфейсов.
Буквально, вот так:

```
services.AddSingleton<Impl>();
services.AddSingleton<IService1>(services => services.GetService<Impl>());
services.AddSingleton<IService2>(services => services.GetService<Impl>());
```

Это также должно сработать для `Scoped`-сервисов.